how to access registered enterprise application properties from azure
I have an Azure Application name and I would like to know if there is a way to get the application ID and other properties of the enterprise application.
I am able to authenticate myself by passing in the clientID/ApplicationID and secret. But, I would like to know if there is a way to fetch client id/application ID using Azure Application name, so that I dont have to hardcode it.

Could you confirm whether you have access to login Azure using PowerShell or CLI commands?

i have access for both. also is there any way i can access it through c#.

Then you can login as user and run list applications query filtering with application name.

any options without user? i am looking for an available public api which exposes application properties.

Without user, you need client ID to authenticate but that's your main ask

is there any public api which exposes application properties ?

You mean http request that can be run in browser? You can make use of Graph Explorer and run GET applications query filtering with application name but need to sign in to Graph Explorer first before running any query

yes http request. is any http available other than graph explorer?

AFAIK, there is no other possible way that exposes application properties without knowing client ID or logging in as user

I have one enterprise application named "DemoApp" with below properties:

To fetch client ID (app ID) using application name, you can make use of below commands:
PowerShell:
Connect-AzAccount
$enterpriseApp = Get-AzADServicePrincipal -DisplayName "DemoApp"
$enterpriseApp.AppId


Azure CLI:
az login
az ad sp list --display-name "DemoApp" --query "[0].appId"


Microsoft Graph:
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/servicePrincipals/?$filter=displayName eq 'DemoApp' &$select=appId,appDisplayName



can i access this graphapi endpoint thru apim service?

Regarding accessing Graph API endpoint through APIM service, feel free to post a new question with more details and share the link here

Please add more details to the question by editing it. As per SO guidelines, question should at least have code you tried, Portal images and errors if any.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79163292/how-to-integrate-graph-api-in-apim-service  please add your comments here
