how to integrate graph api in apim service
I have an Azure Application name and I can access the enterprise application properties with the help of graph Api.
I want to integrate the below graph Api into my APIM service for fetching the properties. Is there any reference for creating a mock Api in Api management service?
Microsoft Graph:
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/servicePrincipals/?$filter=displayName eq 'Demo App' &$select=appId,appDisplayName
can i use the policies "rewrite-uri" for generating token and then pass it to the "send-request".
or is there any simple way available for integration?

To generate access token, what authentication method you are using? You need client ID of application while generating token too

i am using https://login.microsoftonline.com//oauth2/v2.0/token

What grant_type you are using to generate the token?  client_credentials?

yes client_credentials

In that case, you need client ID and client secret beforehead to generate the token and use it to call Graph API

yes i have the values. i need working code snippets to call oauth api from apim

Hi @VaraLakshmi Any update?

Initially, I registered one application and granted Application.Read.All Microsoft Graph permission of Application type with admin consent as below:

Make sure to add redirect URI as "https://authorization-manager.consent.azure-apim.net/redirect/apim/YOUR-APIM-SERVICENAME" in Web platform of application as below:

Now, create credential provider in your APIM service with Identity provider as Azure Active Directory v1, grant type as client credentials and resource URL as https://graph.microsoft.com like this:

Under Connection tab, enter client ID and client secret values of your app registration with connection name:

You can confirm it by checking the status of connection, visiting newly created credential provider like this:

Create new HTTP API with "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0" as Web service URL:

Create GET operation in it with URL as /servicePrincipals :

Make use of below sample policy file code that generates token and use it to call Graph API:
<policies>
    <inbound>
        <base />
        <get-authorization-context provider-id="graphcred01" authorization-id="graphconnection" context-variable-name="auth-context" identity-type="managed" ignore-error="false" />
        <set-header name="Authorization" exists-action="override">
            <value>@("Bearer " + ((Authorization)context.Variables.GetValueOrDefault("auth-context"))?.AccessToken)</value>
        </set-header>
        <!-- Rewrite URI to include filter and select parameters, with properly escaped characters -->
        <rewrite-uri template="/servicePrincipals/?$filter=displayName eq &apos;DemoApp&apos;&amp;$select=appId,appDisplayName" />
    </inbound>
    <backend>
        <base />
    </backend>
    <outbound>
        <base />
    </outbound>
    <on-error>
        <base />
    </on-error>
</policies>

Response:

Reference:
Create connection to Microsoft Graph API - Azure API Management | Microsoft
